# ViteJS React Parsing Error: Missing '@babel/plugin-bugfix-safari-id-destructuring-collision-in-function-expression

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, vite, internal-server-error, parsing-error

We have a vitejs react application which is throwing an internal server error:
 `0:0  error  Parsing error: [BABEL]: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-bugfix-safari-id-destructuring-collision-in-function-expression'`

Tried to install @babel/plugin-bugfix-safari-id-destructuring-collision-in-function-expression as a dev dependency and added the same in .babelrc but the issue still persists.

Comment: SOLUTION

One solution which worked for me was to downgrade the node version. I downgraded the version to 16.20.2.
The thing which I noticed was, this issue occurs in the latest node version